# ajax call doesn't work in modal call in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

first, sorry for my English !
I tried to explain my problem :
I have a modal (bootstrap) who is populate with an ajax call, in this modal I have a form and the submission is in ajax.
When I call the modal I have no problem, the form is display fine but when I submit the form (with ajax) nothing append, the function is called ok (if i put a console.log in the called function I have the trace) but the ajax call not work ...
Here is my process :
first I have a button who call the first ajax to open the modal with the goof form :

```
<a class="btn btn-info _filemanager waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#defaultModal" data-id="course_visuel">Carte et bandeau</a>
```

in the modal I have a form call with this code :

```
$(document).on('click', '._filemanager', function(){
 $('#default-modal-content').html(spinner());
 var input = $(this).data('id');
 $.ajax({
     url: '/ged/ajax/dialog',
     type: 'POST',
     data: 'input=' + input,
     processData: false,
     dataType: false,
     cache: false,
     getScript: true,
     async: true,
 })
 .done(function(s) {
     var res = jQuery.parseJSON(s);
     if(res.status == 'success') {
         $('#default-modal-content').html(res.html);
         $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
     }
 });
});
```

here is the code from the form :

```
<form id="formFolderGed">
            <div class="form-group md-form">
                <input class="form-control" name="ged_folders_name" type="text" required>
                <label for="ged_folders_name">{{ l.folder_name }}<sup class="text-red"><b>*</b></sup></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group md-form">
                <label for="ged_folders_id" class="active">{{ l.choose_parent }}</label>
                <select name="ged_folders_id" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary">
                    <option value="{{ parents.ged_folders_id }}">{{ parents.ged_folders_name }}</option>
                    {{ _self.selectFolder(parents, 1) }}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="panelFooter">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit">{{ l.submit }}</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm _openFolderForm" type="button">{{ l.annule }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

when I submit the form, I call this function :

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#formFolderGed', function(e){
$('#default-modal-content').html(spinner());
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: '/ged/ajax/dialog',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    async: true,
})
.done(function(s) {
    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(s);
    if(res.status == 'success') {
        $('#default-modal-content').html(res.html);
    }
});
});
```

the first ajax call is ok but when I submit the form ... no ajax, if I do that :

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#formFolderGed', function(e){
   console.log('ok');
   .......
```

I have the 'ok' in the console but the ajax call doesn't work (no trace in the network/xhr panel in the console) ...
Where is my mistake ?????
Thanks for your help !